# FormData with nested arrays to JS Object

Tags: javascript, json, object, multidimensional-array, form-data

I've seen lots of posts on how to do the opposite, nested object to FormData, and basic FormData to Object, but I'm trying to convert FormData with nested arrays to an object.

The FormData contains nested/multidimensional array data so running through FormData.entires() does not work as this produces:

```
{
    "key": value,
    "items[0][key1]": value,
    "items[0][key2]": value,
    "items[1][key1]": value,
    "items[1][key2]": value
}
```

whereas what I need it to produce is:

```
{
    "key": value,
    "items": [
        {
            "key1": value,
            "key2": value
        },
        {
            "key1": value,
            "key2": value
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this possible without using a mess of regex?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to construct a form semantically, then extract the data as it needs to be sent to the server as JSON

Comment: But, How do I know, `items[0]` is an array ? It could be an object `{ 0: value }`

Comment: So`items[0][key1]: value` could be `{ items : { 0: { key1: value } } }`

Comment: You're absolutely right, generally speaking it could be, but I'm specifically treating it as an array

Comment: Did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up swapping to using a dot notation (key1.0.keyA) in my names and using the dot-object package like so:

```
export const formDataToObject = (formData) => {
  const object = {};
  formData.forEach(function(value, key) {
    DotObject.set(key, value, object);
  });

  // Filter out unset/undefined items
  Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
    if (Array.isArray(object[key])) {
      object[key] = [...object[key]].filter(Boolean);
    }
  });

  return object;
};
```

Comment: there is also has a function called [dot.object()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-object#expand-to-an-object) try it out... Also checkout my answer 